# Calculating average slope using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, slope, road

[image]

I want to rate for ease of walkability for one track, I have a road shapefile and raster of the slope.

Any ideas about how to calculate average slope or other methods to do that?

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far?

Comment: tried to create a slope profile line chart and get mean result

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. I recommend providing a detailed description of precisely what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the **[Add Surface Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm)** tool. You need 3D Analyst Extension for this.